# How to store and count the number of times a value is entered into a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i have the following example where i retrieve an ID

```
DECLARE @ScheduleId NVARCHAR (max),@DateTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(8) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@DateTime,112)
SET @ScheduleId = (SELECT TOP 1 sc.ScheduleID
FROM dbo.Subscriptions s WITH(NOLOCK) inner join dbo.ReportSchedule sc WITH(NOLOCK) on s.SubscriptionID=sc.SubscriptionID
WHERE LastRunTime>=@Date and LastRunTime< @Date
```

the above gets me a ScheduleID,this works fine. I have a column named COUNT as shown bellow, what i am trying to achieve is that when the schedule ID is returned it must be entered into the table but it must count the number of times it has been entered.
for example:

if the schedule ID when i run the above query returns `@ScheduleID='DREVJHIS-59545GRTHS`'
then it must insert into the table

```
insert into Table (ScheduleID,Count)
values(@scheduleID,count // how do i do a count here)
```

Table

```
ScheduleID          | Count
DREVJHIS-59545GRTHS |   1 

//so the 1 would mean that  only one time does this specific ID exists in this table
```

if i run the query again and it comes back with the same ID then the count column should be updated as follows

```
ScheduleID          | Count
DREVJHIS-59545GRTHS |   2   // so here now it shows that 2 times the id has been entered into this table.
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: are you inserting over and over again or are you inserting once and updating over and over again?

Comment: insert once if the ID doesnt exists and then update after that

Comment: Using With(Noclock) is [bad practise](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    if Not Exists (Select 1 from Table where ScheduleID = @ScheduleID)
Begin
insert into Table (ScheduleID,Count)
values(@scheduleID,1)
End
else
Begin
Update Table set Count = Count + 1 Where ScheduleID = @ScheduleID
End
```

Comment: Thanks this helped,if i want to prevent nulls from been inserted?

Comment: If this helped; then you can accept it as an answer or vote the answer up; for the null values you can post it in another question as it is far away from this post. @George

Answer (score 0):

This will also count null values being inserted:

Test table:

```
CREATE table yourtable(ScheduleID varchar(20), Count INT)
```

Syntax:

```
DECLARE @ScheduleID varchar(20) = 'DREVJHIS-59545GRTHS'

;Merge yourtable t1
USING
(SELECT 0 x) t2
ON exists
  (
    SELECT t1.ScheduleID 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT @ScheduleID
  )
WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE
SET count += 1
WHEN not matched THEN
INSERT (ScheduleID, Count)
VALUES(@ScheduleID, 1);
```